# No function matches the given name and argument types

Tags: sql, postgresql

В СУБД `postgres` есть таблица `address`, содержащая в себе координаты и адреса:

```
database=# \d address
                               Table "public.api_taskaddress"
  Column   |          Type           |                          Modifiers                           
-----------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer                 | not null default nextval('address_id_seq'::regclass)
 longitude | double precision        | 
 latitude  | double precision        | 
 address   | character varying(1000) |
```

Необходимо написать функцию, которая бы высчитывала координаты между адресом и местоположением человека:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION distance (lat1 REAL, long1 REAL, lat2 REAL, long2 REAL) RETURNS REAL AS '
DECLARE 
    x REAL = 69.1 * (lat1 - lat2);
    y REAL = 69.1 * (long1 - long2) * cos (lat1 / 57.3);
BEGIN
    RETURN sqrt(x*x + y*y);
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Но при вызове функции выскакивает ошибка:

```
database=# SELECT distance(latitude, longitude, 68.0, 57.0) FROM address;
ERROR:  function distance(double precision, double precision, numeric, numeric) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT distance(latitude, longitude, 68.0, 57.0) FROM api_ta...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Можете подсказать, как быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: К PostgreSQL имеется расширение [PostGIS](http://gis-lab.info/docs/postgis/manual/), позволяющее хранить и обрабатывать географические данные. Возможно, вам и текущих костылей хватит, но все же, рекомендую ознакомиться с ним, найдете много вкусностей.

Comment: @Vitalts, про PostGIS знаю, но там были свои проблемы. Чуть позже создам вопрос про него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в приведении типов. В функции ожидается параметр типа `REAL`, а приходит `DOUBLE PRECISION`. Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT * distance(CAST (latitude AS REAL, ...)
```

Вот [тут](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/typeconv-func.html) можно почитать подробнее.

Comment: Я только что создал функцию так: `distance (lat1 double precision, long1 double precision, lat2 REAL, long2 REAL)`. Не знал, что можно задавать такой тип данных.